# Как распарсить Excel файл используя Python и прогнать через цикл?

Tags: python, excel

Всем привет! Я новенький в Py, далеко не всё знаю. Что имеем -
Табилца Excel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо распарсить все эти данные и по одному хосту отправлять POST запрос на стороннюю API. Метод POST-запроса с входными параметрами уже есть, но данные я вписываю через `Input()`. Но я не знаю как реализовать такой функционал -

Распарсить данные в файле Excel -> по одному хосту юзать метод -> и так до последнего хоста в таблице.

Я не знаю как это реализовать на Python. На Swift это было бы так - необходимо было создать модель данных, присвоить массиву этот элемент данных как тип и через цикл прогнать все данные, используя какой-то метод.

Заранее, огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xlrd    
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('Ваш файл')
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
vals = [sheet.row_values(rownum) for rownum in range(1, sheet.nrows)]
```

в vals будут Ваши строки в виде списка